One custom taxonomy with unique sets of labels for two post types?
I’m trying to use one custom taxonomy with different labels for different post types. I have the default “post” post type, and a “podcast” post type. Both post types have an associated Taxonomy with the taxonomy “author” (separate from the Wordpress user who created the post). For “post” type posts, I want to use labels referring to this custom taxonomy as “Author” - “Add Author”, “Back to Authors”, etc. For the “podcast” posts, I want to use labels referring to the taxonomy as “Speakers”. This way, I can pull all the content a given person has been written/featured on into given archives. I know there is the filter “taxonomy_labels_{taxonomy}”, but when I modify the taxonomy’s labels there, it changes the labels for all post types.
Is there a clean way to use one set of labels for one post type, and another set of labels for another post type, while keeping the same slug/underlying taxonomy?
In the absolute worst case, I could make do with using one set of labels for the taxonomy, but this would make it a bit easier for users who are uploading content. The 'brute force' option, I think, would be to use custom meta boxes to set the posts terms, and control the labelling there, but this would not change the labels in the admin editor.
